# Добавление записи в базу

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Я новичок в PHP. У меня в URL есть /rezultat.php?page=4, это универсальная страница,  как сделать чтобы при добавлении записи в бд, id автоматически заполнялся 4, если 5 то 5 итд

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!!!))) Хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: `$id = $_GET['page']`,а потом просто делай выборку из БД, можно и без `PDO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас поле в которое заносится id должен быть не auto-increment. Для добавления ID передавайте его в метод посредством массива `$_GET['page']`

Answer (score 0):

Смотри PDO - http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php

Тебе нужны методы PDO prepare, PDOStatement execute, PDOStatement fetchAll

Answer (score -1):

В вашем URL есть GET запрос. На странице где все записи:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('ваш хост','логин','пароль','база данных');
if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `table`")){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$count1 = $row[0];
$count2 = $row[1];
$page = $row[2];
echo "<a href='resultat.php?page=".$page."'>Ссылка</a>";
}
}
?>
```

На странице resultat.php нужно обработать этот запрос:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    //теперь его можно вывести так с помощью echo $page; либо дальше его использовать
//например можно сделать подключение к бд и взять оттуда запись с этим значением
$link = mysqli_connect('ваш хост','логин','пароль','база данных');
if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `ваша таблица` WHERE `значение столбца` = '$page'")){
//если все получилось то вынимаем значения
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id = $row['id'];//значение в row['id'] - это столбец в вашей таблице, он может иметь и другие значения. Дальше вы можете взять значения других столбцов. Например 
$title = $row['title'];
}
echo 'В базе есть ID='.$id.' с таким значением '.$title;
}
    }
    ?>
```

Так же прочитайте чем отличается mysqli_fecth_row от mysqli_fetch_assoc;
Прочитайте о том как получать и отправлять GET и POST запросы, и чем они отличаются друг от друга

Comment: Знайте, что при использовании такого подхода к составлению sql запросов вы получите взлом сайта, так как тут есть уязвимость типа SQL injection.